# Create NLOG file with latest message only

Tags: nlog

Is there any way to create a log file with NLOG will just contain the latest message.  Basically I don't want to append to the log and have it only contain the latest message.  The goal is to create a log file out of each of hundreds of processes that are running so I can have a separate process look at those logs to verify that a process is up and running.

Comment: I am probably just going to create a simple log not using NLOG since I don't this request is really the intended uses of NLOG.

Comment: yes, definitely not the goal of NLog. another method is suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File target has a property replaceFileContentsOnEachWrite - indicates whether to replace file contents on each write instead of appending log message at the end.

http://nlog-project.org/wiki/File_target#File_replaceFileContentsOnEachWrite